# Create an alert's message out of < 2 R.string.id texts

Tags: java, android, alert

I'm creating an `alert` which should display a **variable** inside its display message.

So I've created a `R.string.dialog_message1` and a `R.string.dialog_message2` to put before and then this variable. This is what I achieved:

```
 builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message1 + lastOnes + R.string.dialog_message2)
            .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title );
```

I get no errors until I get to the runtime process.

It displays:

"Submit query" instead that my own mixed message, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look like:

```
builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_message1) + lastOnes + getString(R.string.dialog_message2)).setTitle(getString(R.string.dialog_title));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `R.string.stringname1` calls are returning the String resource ids, not the Strings themselves. [This example from Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) will show you how to properly use String resources.